# Simple caching makes GC go crazy?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm using C# 3.5 and VS 2010 ultimate.

I'm optimizing (for speed) a machine learning algorithm that has four nested for-loops.
I've found that a simple cache (a tensor of objects) could potentially greatly improve the performance, because there's a lot of re-allocating of the same objects.

Here's the before and after implementations.

Before:

```
four nested for-loops:
   var object = new object(3 parameters);
   Calculate(object, other params)
```

After:

```
var cache = new object[count1,count2,count3];
three nested for-loops:
   cache[param1, param2, param3] = new object(3 params);

four nested for-loops:
   var object = cache[3 parameters];
   Calculate(object, other params)
```

I've profiled both methods and the "before" version was quite faster with ~18% time spent in GC, while the "after" version spend ~88% in GC.
It's obvious that the addition of this cache made the GC activity rise, but I'm failing to see how this is possible.

I am using many long-lived object in the application. My machine wasn't under heavy load at the time of profiling. The tensor was implemented using multi-dimensional array (not jagged arrays). The inner-most loop in both methods above is implemented using the `Parallel.For` construct, where right before the loop I am allocating a small `double` array.

How can I reduce the time spent in GC?

EDIT #1: The results are indeed from Release mode.

EDIT #2: Real code of the after method's four for-loop:

```
List<int> labels = // count = 80
List<int> tokens = // count = 35

var table = new double[tokens.Count, labels.Count, labels.Count];
var cachedObjects = new CachedObject[tokens.Count, labels.Count, labels.Count];
for (int k = 0; k < tokens.Count; k++)
{
    foreach (var tagCurrent in labels) 
    {
        foreach (var labelBack in labels)
        {
            double[] value = new double[labels.Count];
            Parallel.For(0, labels.Count, (i) => 
            {
                CachedObject CachedObject = cachedObjects[k, labelsBackFurther[i], labelBack];

                var me = ModelEstimate(vOptimal, CachedObject, tagCurrent, labels);
                value[i] = table[k - 1, labels[i], labelBack] * me;
            }); 

            var maxValue = 0;
            var maxTagIdx = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < value.Length; j++)
            {
                var item = value[j];
                if (item > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = item;
                    maxTagIdx = j;
                }
            }

            table[k, labelBack, tagCurrent] = maxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132033/reasons-for-seeing-high-time-in-gc-in-perf-mon

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd show real code - simplified to remove extraneous things, but real in terms of everything important. The pseudo-code is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @JonSkeet is certainly right here. One other thing to note is that if you profiled this in `Debug` configuration all numbers are irrelevant. Please make sure that the numbers you provided were in fact snapshots of a `Release` build with optimizations included.

Comment: How big are the arrays of doubles? I'm thinking about the large object heap...

Comment: Eighty elements in this instance, but can be anywhere between 4 and 200. Also note that the array of doubles are present in both of aforementioned methods.

Comment: .Net allocates any object equal to or above 80KB in either gen 1 or gen 2. If lot of reallocation happening that could mean that your objects are very close to 80KB like say 75KB to 79KB and are getting allocated in gen 0 and resulting in lot of reallocation. Try to profile size of your objects.

Comment: Could there be additional boxing/unboxing due to the cache?

Comment: This isn't the first example of an 'assumed optimization' having averse effects. The GC is very efficient when dealing with short lived objects. Caching is usually more expensive and forces more memory to Gen-1 and even Gen-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GC is affected by two factors: Number of allocations and number of survivors.

Allocations trigger collects, so the more you allocate the more frequent collects.

If the app holds on to a lot of data then Gen 2 collections may become very expensive. If you see much time spent in GC this is usually the case (collecting Gen 0 and 1 is fast as these are limited in size).

In your case it sounds like you want to hold on to the cache. If you do that, you need to make sure you keep allocations down as you don't want to trigger expensive Gen 2 collects.

You can use [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to track allocations.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may have heap overhead from the use of Parallel.For (try using bigger chunk sizes).
2. ModelEstimate may have heap overhead.
   Run the [CLRProfiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273) using the appropriate version for your framework. It will tell you what you are allocating and exactly what is happening in the heap.

Environment variable:

> OMV_PATH=C:\WINDOWS\Temp  Indicates where to put the log file.

Comment: Is there a way to tell CLRProfiler to _not_ write the huge log file in C:\Windows\Temp? Mind you, my environmental vars TMP and TEMP is set to somewhere else already as I don't have space on C: drive...

Comment: I've replaced Parallel.For with a regular for-loop. The GC activity increased a few percents.

Comment: To make CLRProfiler easier to use, reduce the number of allocations in general, by reducing the size of your arrays, if possible (make a less accurate optimization result). Or you can kill your process in the middle of the run.

Comment: Parallel.For must be the culprit. Check out Partitioner.Create: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx

Comment: No, the caching is the culprit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you please explain? Since we have no code to run, it is difficult to see why the cache would cause different behavior depending on the type of loop (parallel or serial). In both cases the same number of objects are created for the cache, I assume.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Never mind, I understand now, the parallelization did not cause the problem, it was the caching. I misread the response.

Answer (score 1):

The cache could be placing additional memory overhead on your application, which in turn causes the application to run with a smaller amount of free memory available for other purposes. In this situation, the garbage collector is not only forced to run more frequently, but is often less efficient as the memory load grows as a percentage of the overall memory available for your application.

If you have sufficient system memory, try rerunning your application as a 64-bit application to see if the problem continues.

Depending on the number of cache elements in use at once, you could be causing as many as `count1*count2*count3 - 1` objects to be unnecessarily prevented from being collected, along with the multidimensional array itself.

Comment: The application eats ~200MB of memory. I've tried running it on a system with 4GB and 8GB (both in 64bit) mode.

Answer (score 0):

How can I reduce the time spent in GC?

There is a very interesting suggestion found in the "[Garbage Collection Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647790.aspx)" by Microsoft which states

> Consider using weak references when you work with cached data, so that
>   cached objects can be resurrected easily if needed or released by
>   garbage collection when there is memory pressure.

Example

```
void SomeMethod() 
{
  // Create a collection
  var arr = new ArrayList(5);
  // Create a custom object
  var mo = new MyObject();
  // Create a WeakReference object from the custom object
  var wk = new WeakReference(mo);
  // Add the WeakReference object to the collection
  arr.Add(wk);
  // Retrieve the weak reference
  WeakReference weakReference = (WeakReference)arr[0];
  MyObject mob = null;
  if( weakReference.IsAlive ){
    mob = (MyOBject)weakReference.Target;
  }
  if(mob==null){
    // Resurrect the object as it has been garbage collected
  }
  //continue because we have the object
}
```