# What is the meaning of "% Time in GC" performance counter

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm using the `perfcounter = "% Time in GC"`

So when I run

```
gcPerf.NextSample()
```

I get the value 42.12273.

But I don't understand the units of this values is it in (ms) or what ?

If I want it in (ms) how I can transform it ?

Here is the global code

```
 string category = ".NET CLR Memory";
 string counter  = "% Time in GC";
 string instance = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
 PerformanceCounter gcPerf;

 // make sure the performance counter is available to query
 if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(category) &&
     PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counter, category) &&
     PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instance, category))
 {
    gcPerf = new PerformanceCounter(category, counter, instance);
 }
```

Comment: It's a percentage of elapsed time. Have you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e(v=vs.110).aspx#memory)? What isn't clear about it?

Comment: If it's a percentage how i'll calculate it in (ms) ? because process.TotalProcessorTime give all the time including GC and how i can substrut GC time from it to have just the cpu time without GC time ?

Answer (score 4):

> This is the percentage of the time spent in GC since the end of the
>   last GC. For example, it’s been 1 million cycles since last GC ended
>   and we spent 0.3 million cycles in the current GC, this counter will
>   show 30%.

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132033/reasons-for-seeing-high-time-in-gc-in-perf-mon).

> What is a health value for this counter? It’s hard to say. It depends
>   on what your app does. But if you are seeing a really high value (like
>   50% or more) then it’s a reasonable time to look at what’s going on
>   inside of the managed heap. If this number is 10%, it’s probably
>   better to look elsewhere in your app because even if you could get rid
>   of half of that, you would only be saving 5% - most likely not very
>   worthwhile.

Comment: If i want it in (ms) how i can transform it ?

Comment: @CharithJ the first link is broken, or at least it gives a 403. Do you have another link to this resource?